# to pass a variable from a method to the main body

Tags: class, methods

I made a code to compare 2 times . The structure of the code constitutes of a main body getting the 2 times. A class and 2 methods are converting the times into second just to make an integer. The problem is that the variable showing the integer  doesn't pass to the main body. The code is as follow.

```
    class Time():
def __init__(self, other=None):
    

self.other = other

def comparison(self, other):
    

        self.other = other
            return other > self
        def time_to_int(self, other):
            self.other = other
            other = self.hour * 3600 + self.minute * 60 + self.second
            print( other )
    start = Time()
    start.hour = 2.0
    start.minute = 87
    start.second = 98
    start_time = Time()
    start.time_to_int( start_time )
    end = Time()
    end.hour = 3.0
    end.minute = 87
    end.second = 98
    end_time = Time()
    end.time_to_int( end_time )
    print( start_time, end_time )
    start_time.comparison( end_time )
```

The result is

```
12518.0
16118.0
<__main__.Time object at 0x7f9ca1854110> <__main__.Time object at 0x7f9ca18541d0>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-dc5298ddf4b1> in <module>()
     31 
     32 
---> 33 start_time.comparison(end_time)
     34 

<ipython-input-1-dc5298ddf4b1> in comparison(self, other)
      5     def comparison(self, other):
      6       self.other=other
----> 7       return other > self
      8     def time_to_int(self, other):
      9       self.other=other

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Time' and 'Time'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make yourself familiar with how to include code blocks (i.e. use triple backticks ```) and mention which programming language you are using.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question correctly (after all, you haven't been asking one...), but _"The problem is that the variable showing the integer doesn't pass to the main body."_ sounds as if you wanted to use a `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your `comparison` method uses `other > self`, and the `TypeError` tells you that this is not defined. What's your question?